# parse part of the text from regex pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string:

```
[\n['-','some text what\rcontains\nnewlines'],\n\n
```

trying to parse:

```
Regex.Split(@"[\n['-','some text what contains newlines'],\n\n", @"\[\n\['(.*)','(.*)'],.*");
```

but the split return array seems to be null

i need to get part of text:  "some text what contains newlines"

Comment: Does the string have actual newline characters or the two characters `\n`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the `Match` function, which will give the the capture groups.

For example:

```
Regex.Match("[\n['-','some text what\rcontains\nnewlines'],\n\n", @"\[\n\['(.*)','(.*)'],.*", RegexOptions.Singleline).Groups[2].Value
```

`RegexOptions.Singleline` is necessary to force `.` to match `\n`.

Answer (score 0):

The wildcard '.' does not recognize newlines by default. Use the RegexOptions.Singleline to specify that period should match newlines.

Also checkout [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm), a great tool for working with C# Regex.